# How to solve this Error : Gradle task assembleDebug failed with exit code 1

Tags: android-studio, flutter

I installed Android Studio 4.1 and installed all of SDK and JDK 8 and etc.
When I want to run this `flutter run` in my project, I see this error:

```
C:\Users\Farshad\Desktop\myapp>flutter run
Launching lib\main.dart on Nokia 6 1 in debug mode...
Exception in thread "main" java.io.IOException: Unable to tunnel through proxy. Proxy returns "HTTP/1.1 403 Request blocked by Privoxy"
        at sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection.doTunneling(HttpURLConnection.java:2152)
        at sun.net.www.protocol.https.AbstractDelegateHttpsURLConnection.connect(AbstractDelegateHttpsURLConnection.java:183)
        at sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection.followRedirect0(HttpURLConnection.java:2739)
        at sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection.followRedirect(HttpURLConnection.java:2651)
        at sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection.getInputStream0(HttpURLConnection.java:1830)
        at sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection.getInputStream(HttpURLConnection.java:1498)
        at sun.net.www.protocol.https.HttpsURLConnectionImpl.getInputStream(HttpsURLConnectionImpl.java:268)
        at org.gradle.wrapper.Download.downloadInternal(Download.java:58)
        at org.gradle.wrapper.Download.download(Download.java:44)
        at org.gradle.wrapper.Install$1.call(Install.java:61)
        at org.gradle.wrapper.Install$1.call(Install.java:48)
        at org.gradle.wrapper.ExclusiveFileAccessManager.access(ExclusiveFileAccessManager.java:65)
        at org.gradle.wrapper.Install.createDist(Install.java:48)
        at org.gradle.wrapper.WrapperExecutor.execute(WrapperExecutor.java:128)
        at org.gradle.wrapper.GradleWrapperMain.main(GradleWrapperMain.java:61)
Running Gradle task 'assembleDebug'...
Running Gradle task 'assembleDebug'... Done                        17.9s
[!] Gradle threw an error while downloading artifacts from the network. Retrying to download...
Exception in thread "main" java.io.IOException: Unable to tunnel through proxy. Proxy returns "HTTP/1.1 403 Request blocked by Privoxy"
        at sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection.doTunneling(HttpURLConnection.java:2152)
        at sun.net.www.protocol.https.AbstractDelegateHttpsURLConnection.connect(AbstractDelegateHttpsURLConnection.java:183)
        at sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection.followRedirect0(HttpURLConnection.java:2739)
        at sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection.followRedirect(HttpURLConnection.java:2651)
        at sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection.getInputStream0(HttpURLConnection.java:1830)
        at sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection.getInputStream(HttpURLConnection.java:1498)
        at sun.net.www.protocol.https.HttpsURLConnectionImpl.getInputStream(HttpsURLConnectionImpl.java:268)
        at org.gradle.wrapper.Download.downloadInternal(Download.java:58)
        at org.gradle.wrapper.Download.download(Download.java:44)
        at org.gradle.wrapper.Install$1.call(Install.java:61)
        at org.gradle.wrapper.Install$1.call(Install.java:48)
        at org.gradle.wrapper.ExclusiveFileAccessManager.access(ExclusiveFileAccessManager.java:65)
        at org.gradle.wrapper.Install.createDist(Install.java:48)
        at org.gradle.wrapper.WrapperExecutor.execute(WrapperExecutor.java:128)
        at org.gradle.wrapper.GradleWrapperMain.main(GradleWrapperMain.java:61)
Running Gradle task 'assembleDebug'...
Running Gradle task 'assembleDebug'... Done                         8.9s
[!] Gradle threw an error while downloading artifacts from the network. Retrying to download...
Exception: Gradle task assembleDebug failed with exit code 1
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

if you are from iran and cuba or syria or other some other countries 
this error will be showing
because of filtering, i think android studio forbade those countries
you can use vpn and try again please tell me the result

Comment: check this site and define mentioned DNS to your pc DNS and try again https://shecan.ir/

Comment: for doing that ,first turn the vpn off

Comment: i tested this solution but for this command ' Flutter run ' doesnt work well :(((((( Do you think the problem is from the internet?

Comment: no , it happens to me every week ,but when i am using `sheckan` it goes away , i suggest you to use other vpns ,and make sure that vpn works well , there is another way to do,it is kind of risky , go to `C:\Users\YOURUSER NAME` and try to find , gradle folder, remove it and turn vpn on and try again , tell me the result

Comment: with any vpn ! windscribe , proton , cisco anyconnect , tunnel plus and .... i tested this command but i dont know why it happens !??  i tired of this difficults of developing in iran :(((

Comment: Hey bro! thanks ! this way that delete gradle folder is well ! Done !!!! Thanks Brooooo :)))